# How to get bash-style autocompletion in zsh, (for git command)

Tags: bash, shell, git, zsh, autocomplete

I switched to **zsh** and find it better than **bash**, but I have a problem with **oh-my-zsh**'s (hereafter "**OMZ**") autocomplete feature.

When I type `git chec`, OMZ completes that to `git check`; in **bash** it gets completed to `git checkout`.  I have also a problem with remote branches:  `ori` completed to `oriG`, and `orig` to `origin`, in **bash** it gets completed to `origin/`

I have the same problem with other **git** commands like `checkout`.

I think the problem is the *aliases* added by the plugin. I don't use them, as I don't want to get used to them, but they break auto-completion for me.

Is there any way to get the **bash** autocomplete (I know there isn't a built-in autocomplete in bash) in **zsh**?  Or a way to hack the OMZ plugin so that it doesn't break at each update.

Comment: There is no "git plugin" in vanilla `zsh`. So, by "the git plugin" you are referring to the git plugin for *oh-my-zsh*, are you not? And I suspect you mean Tab-completion instead of autocompletion. The difference being that the first one only completes after pressing **Tab** and the latter one does so automatically by just typing the the normal commands. Both is possible in `zsh`, so I have to ask.

Comment: Yes I use the plugin from oh-my-zsh and I refer to Tab-completion

Comment: Are you aware that you can press TAB twice to see available options? That generally tells you why completion stopped where it did. Also note that with zsh / omz completion is configured not to be case sensitive by default.

Comment: In addition to @barbaz' comment above, just type `git che` then hit  the `<tab>` key four times to cycle through the completion options.

Answer (score 5):

Completion and where it comes from can be rather confusing. Take a Ubuntu 14.04 system as an example:

```
$ dpkg -L zsh-common | grep git
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Debian/_git-buildpackage
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_stgit
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_git
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_topgit
/usr/share/zsh/functions/VCS_Info/Backends/VCS_INFO_get_data_git
/usr/share/zsh/functions/VCS_Info/Backends/VCS_INFO_detect_git
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Misc/run-help-git
```

The `zsh-common` package ships git completion functions. On the other hand, the `git` package also comes with completion files for bash and zsh:

```
$ dpkg -L git | grep compl
/etc/bash_completion.d
/etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt
/usr/share/bash-completion
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/gitk
```

Which contains files such as

```
$ head -n 5 /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/gitk
# bash/zsh completion support for core Git.
#
# Copyright (C) 2006,2007 Shawn O. Pearce <spearce@spearce.org>
# Conceptually based on gitcompletion (http://gitweb.hawaga.org.uk/).
# Distributed under the GNU General Public License, version 2.0.
```

The git package even provides a git aware prompt which can be enabled, all without fancy addons such as oh-my-zsh.

To summarize, git subcommand completion can come from your shell (zsh):

https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Completion/Unix/Command/_git

from git

https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/completion

or from plugins such as oh-my-zsh.

To get back to your question: The old behavior of completing `git chec` that you describe is actually buggy. `chec` is still ambiguous and a proper completion script should not complete it to `checkout`, since there are multiple subcommands that begin with `chec`. If you want that behavior, find out which of the many completion scripts out there you were using before, disable the oh-my-zsh git plugin and continue to use your old completion script.

Alternatively, I'd recommend to set up an alias and get used to it. You can use

```
git config --global alias.co checkout
```

to make `git co` your new `git checkout` - the oh-my-zsh plugin is aware of these aliases and will still complete branch and tag names next!